# Why does my handwritten 尽 look so ugly?

Tags: handwriting

Every time I write 尽 I feel very unsatisfied.  Today's example:

[image]

Something about it feel odd or wrong, and I don't know what.  I feel it's ugly.

**Question**: Why does my handwritten 尽 look so ugly?

Comment: Let me guess. You are a mathematician? I see a quadrilateral :)

Comment: At a glance, your proportions are off. The box should be twice as long as it is tall (your box isn't far from a square), the right-most arc shouldn't be so far right that it damn-near lines up with the box. These are just my thoughts when comparing your handwriting to the computer text, though admittedly that depends on your font. I believe I'm viewing "尽" with the Google Noto Sans CJK font

Comment: In addition to what the others have said, it would help to slant the horizontal stroke parts a few degrees counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

你的字在模仿黑体印刷字（尽）实际上书写印刷字并不美观。

[image: 我写的尽字]

手写汉字要注意间架结构，撇捺的位置，落笔、出笔的形状，点的写法等。

[image: 分析]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1、**—** is too long.Not out on the left side of the 丿

2、**㇏** is too heavy.It should be from heavy to light and sharp at the end

3、The second **丶** is also too long.It should be shorter.It corresponds to the first 丶


Case of 尽

[image]